# Deploying a C# app that uses Microsoft.Ink.dll

Tags: c#, setup-deployment

I have a legacy app that captures signatures. It uses Microsoft.Ink.dll that came from a Windows Tablet SDK. I am maintaining the app on Windows 7 VS 2010 and it runs fine on my box. When I deploy the app to Windows Server 2003 the app fails with the following error:

> Exception during StringFormat: Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the size of the argument list. Datapump error on interface Risk Assessment Signatures: Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {937C1A34-151D-4610-9CA6-A8CC9BDB5D83} failed due to the following error: 80040154.

Regsvr32 on the dll fails.

I assume that this is because related dll's are missing.

Is there any way to delete the old ink dll and use a more modern dll that I can properly deploy? If not what is the best way to deploy this app?

Comment: Is the Server 2003 machine running a 64-bit version? If so, [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1410877/using-microsoft-ink-in-asp-net-on-windows-server-2008) looks like an exact duplicate.

Comment: I'm already compiling for x86 only.