# 64-bit platform:An attempt was made to load an assembly with an incorrect format

Tags: c#, dll, windows-7, 64-bit

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using Microsoft.Ink in ASP.NET on Windows Server 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1410877/using-microsoft-ink-in-asp-net-on-windows-server-2008)

I have a project for 32 bit platform, it is using Microsoft.Ink.dll. I am migrating this project to 64-bit windows 7. I have changed its Target Platform to: Any CPU.
But when I build it I get following error:
An attempt was made to load an assembly with an incorrect format: C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\ink\Microsoft.ink.dll.

How this error can be resolved?

Comment: A lot of times there aren't equivalent 64-bit binaries of some libraries. You'll either need to force 32-bit mode by recompiling in x86 mode, or find and install a 64-bit version of the library in question. (This is general 64-bit advice — I didn't research that library specifically so I'm not sure if one is available or not.)

Answer (score -1):

Go to the 'Configuration Manager' section, on the 'Active solution platform' drop down list select '' and make a new platform with type of 'x64'. It will be the real x64 build version of your solution. Also I made a console app with referencing to Microsoft.Ink.dll and I did change the platform to x64 and everything seems just fine.

Please let me know that what's the detail of OS version you're working in.

Cheers

Comment: changing to x64 is not working.. It seems to be because of SGEN

Comment: @user1527958 - You identified the problem. So address that problem. Mohammad's advice wasn't that great to be honest. My guess you have tons of 32-bit only references if you are linking directly to Microsoft.ink.dll which my guess you did NOT install a 64-bit version of that dll.

Comment: To be honest, when you're working in a 64 bit environment, it does not matter the references app is using were built on x86 or x64 platform. This problem is a matter of configuration, not anything else, cause I just did the same thing and everything works fine. Also as far as I know, changing release or debug version might solve the problem this situation BUT it depends on the environment. AS I SAID.